Recovering metastable states from perturbation theory
In quantum mechanics, metastable states can be considered as states which have a complex energy $E=E_0 + i\Gamma$, where the imaginary part $\Gamma$ is related to the lifetime of the metastable state. This is both underpinned by the S-matrix formalism, where (meta)stable states are given by the poles of the S-matrix, and in very simple cases, we can solve the Schrödinger equation with appropriate BCs directly for the complex energy.
Sometimes, applying a perturbation to a stable bound state will turn it into a metastable state. E.g., the hydrogen atom has a bound $1s$ state, but this becomes unbound if an electric field $V=Fz$ is applied. Similarly, applying a $H^{(1)}=-\lambda x^4$ perturbation to the harmonic oscillator will lead to a metastable state.
When one does perturbation theory for these problems, the resulting perturbation series consists solely of real values and is divergent. The question is - can one recover the complex energy of the metastable state from doing perturbation theory?
The complex part of the energy is usually proportional to something like $e^{1/F}$ or $e^{1/\lambda}$, which cannot appear in a power series, since all its derivatives are zero at $F=0$. However, the real part is well defined and only a small amount away from the unperturbed value.
Thus - why doesn't the perturbation series converge to the real part of the metastable state energy? And is it possible, in some way, to obtain the energy of the metastable state (both real and complex parts) by perturbation theory?
I've heard that metastable lifetimes (i.e., the complex part $\Gamma$) can be calculated by time-dependent perturbation theory, but I've never seen an example of that being done.
